# Expect/send command with special characters - missing close-brace

Tags: unix, expect, send

I am trying to run a shell script with expect, send commands for SFTP automation.  But, i am ending up with an error 'missing closed brace'.

Could you please help, what i am doing wrong. Issue seems to be with the password having special characters. Please see below.

```
#!/bin/bash

#CONSTANTS

#LOGGING
LOGFILE="/tmp/logger.log"

#SOURCE INFO
SOURCE_FILE_NAME="*.csv"

#SFTP INFO
FTP_SERVER="abc.com"
FTP_USER="username"
FTP_PWD='[_9G)Wr2h4~ws{u'
FTP_PORT=22
FTP_DROP_DIR="/"
FTP_KEY="privatekey.ppk"


echo "Uploading Files......"

expect <<END #> $LOGFILE
 send "$(date)\r";
 spawn sftp -oIdentityFile="$FTP_KEY" "$FTP_USER@$FTP_SERVER"
 expect "*password: "
 send {[_9G)Wr2h4~ws{u\r}"
 expect "sftp> "
 send "ls -ltr\r"
 expect "sftp> "
# send "mget $SOURCE_FILE_NAME\r"
# expect -timeout -1  "sftp> "
 send "quit\r"
 send "$(date)\r";
END

echo "--------------- END -------------"
```

and here is the error that i am getting.

```
Uploading Files......
spawn sftp -oIdentityFile="privatekey.ppk" username@abc.com
Connecting to abc.com...
username@abc.com's password: missing close-brace
    while executing
"send {[_9G)Wr2h4~ws{u\r}"
 expect "sftp> "
 send "ls -ltr\r"
 expect "sftp> "
# send "mget *.csv..."
--------------- END -------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. i believe escaping all special characters seems to work.

```
send "\[_9G\)Wr2h4~ws\{u\r"
```

Comment: Yes, you're running up against [rule #6](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M10) in Tcl's 12 syntax rules.